# providing animation to an image in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which involves saving images in database.Now i am struck in a problem.I have to animate the image on android emulator.Can anyone help me ..

Thanks in advance
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use 2D animation classes (probably) provided by Android. still, it highly depends on which kind of animation you want to be performed.

Comment: Sorry.. not as of now. :(  will keep looking for it, once i get something good, i'll link you to it

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of animation you are looking at. Simple animations like a fade in/fade out can actually be done with an xml defined anim resource.

Comment: ok,,,,,redGreen blue......do u have any sample code of how to provide animation to image

Comment: You can find a good guide here ... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html